# Op and op Convergence Property Related Question

Tags: convergence

There are some properties of the Op and op notation stated in many statistics textbooks but their proof is given nowhere. I have managed to prove most of them, but I cannot see how the following holds:

$$
(1+o_p(1))^{-1}=O_p(1)
$$

Can anyone show why this property holds in a thorough manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can be shown as follows:
Assume a continuous function $h(x)$ for which it holds that $\text{plim}h(x) = 0$, i.e. that $h(x) = o_p(1) \Rightarrow 1 + h(x) = 1+ o_p(1)$. Set 
$$g(x) = \frac {1}{1+h(x)} \Rightarrow g(x) = \Big(1+o_p(1)\Big)^{-1}$$
But also
$$\text{plim}g(x)=\text{plim} \Big (1+h(x)\Big)^{-1} = \Big[1+\text{plim}h(x)\Big ]^{-1} = 1+0 = 1$$

So we also have $$\text{plim}g(x) = 1 \Rightarrow g(x) = O_p(1)$$
and therefore
$$\Big(1+o_p(1)\Big)^{-1}=O_p(1)$$