# is inverse of 1 + small op(1) equal to 1 + small op(1)?

Tags: convergence, asymptotics

One rule for small op and big Op is

$$
(1+o_p(1))^{-1} = O_p(1)
$$

(on page 13 of Vaart, A. W. van der. (1998). Asymptotic statistics. Cambridge University Press.)

I am curious whether it is true to hold

$$
(1+o_p(1))^{-1} \overset{?}{=} 1+o_p(1)
$$

My thought is that suppose $X_n\rightarrow_p 0$, then $X_n=o_p(1)$. Consider the function $g(x)=1/(1+x)$, then by the continuous mapping theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem), we have

$$
g(X_n)\rightarrow_p g(0) = 1\,.
$$

Is that correct, or am I missing something?

If so, why not use the tight result $(1+o_p(1))^{-1} = 1+o_p(1)$?

If not, is there any counterexample that $(1+o_p(1))^{-1} = O_p(1)$ holds but not $(1+o_p(1))^{-1} = 1+o_p(1)$?

PS: I have checked the proof of the rule in another question,
[Op and op Convergence Property Related Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69525/op-and-op-convergence-property-related-question), and it seems that the answer also applies the continuous mapping theorem. No explanation for the difference between $O_p(1)$ and $1+o_p(1)$.

Comment: Are you sure that the notation "$X_n = 1 + o_p(1)$" has a defined meaning? The sources I have seen (including the wikipedia article for little o in probability notation) only define $X_n = o_p(a_n)$, not $X_n = o_p(a_n) + f(n)$. Maybe the hypothesis should be rewritten to "$(1 - o_p(1))^{-1} - 1 = o_p(1)$"?

Comment: @fblundun, not sure. Yeah, this point might be necessary for a rigorous definition. Just double-checked the textbook, all right-hand sides are either Op or op. But I am guessing for convenient proof, this notation can still be acceptable (and it seems that I came across lots of similar expressions in the proofs). I mean, if in some proof, after some calculation, we obtain $X_n=1+o_p(1)$, then we can easily conclude that $X_n-1\rightarrow_p 0$.

Comment: Maybe the weaker result was simply all the author needed for his/her proof?